# regarding Jesus being God

Tags: jesus, trinity, god

For many years I have thought about the Triune.  My conclusion is that God, Jesus, and the Holy Spirit are one and the same.  God, Jesus and the Holy Spirit have always existed from before time, before creation.  I have been taught that Jesus was sent onto the scene, so to speak, to bridge the gap between man and God.  Jesus was more relatable than God the Father.  But Jesus is God in all ways.  This is my final conclusion about the Trinity.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.   Valid questions here need a specific Bible passage to analyze.

Comment: The doctrine of Modalism was anathematized in the 4th and 5th centuries

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. What the bible actually teaches, like John 20:17 Jesus, has a God as do all men. If God has a God, you have two God's.

Comment: @Finster - Is Jesus God or not according to John 1:1, 20:28, Titus 2:13?

Comment: @Dottard Is Jesus God according to John 20:17? Why must you revert to your specially read proof-texts? John 1:1-3 does not even mention Jesus! Just stick to the facts and you won't need to make another Jesus.

Comment: @Finster - thanks, that answers my question.  You choose which texts are in the Bible.

Answer (score 1):

I rather dislike the popular slogan "Jesus is God", because it obscures the traditional teaching that Christ is BOTH God AND man, in conjunction. I will offer you the explanation given in the Athanasian Creed (because it can be found in the 1662 Anglican "Book of Common Prayer", which is conveniently on my bookshelves).

"God of the substance of his Father, begotten before the worlds; and Man of the substance of his Mother, born in the world.

Perfect God and perfect Man; of a reasonable soul and human flesh subsisting."

The point of that second paragraph is that Jesus is fully human with a fully human mind. The idea that he does not have a fully human mind, only "the mind of God" was condemned in the fourth century as the Apollinarian heresy. Jesus, as such, came into existence at the time of his conception. That's the human side. The divine and human aspects of Christ are united "not by conversion of the Godhead into flesh, but by taking of the Manhood into God".

It took a lot of thinking to arrive at that ancient statement, so we need a lot of thought in order to grasp its implications.

Comment: Although the question may be closed as not being in the right form for the site, I am still up-voting this answer as it is an excellent answer to the individual person who voiced the question. Up-voted +1.